# Infinite Controls, sort of like repeater but without databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So essentially I want to let a customer log multiple activities. This includes a textbox, a dropdown for type of activity, and another textbox for time of day activity was done.

So they'd fill it out for one, then be able to hit "Add another" and another set of controls would appear and they could keep doing this over and over again and then in code behind I'd need to be able to loop thru to get data for each.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Repeaters work with ordinary collections -- are you perhaps thinking that it needs to be bound to a database? (that is not the case)

Comment: @KirkWoll No, I know I can use, say a List, but my question is without using anything (or perhaps with one of these ordinary collections) how would I achieve what I am describing/is it possible?